# Replicating jQuery's .next('a') with vanila javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to achieve following in vanila javascript

```
$('#myElement').next('a').length > 0
```

At the moment I'm at this stage

```
document.getElementById('myElement').nextSibling.length > 0
```

But I need to specifically check if there is an anchor tag `<a>` with class `.item` after `#myDiv`, as there can and cannot be one, and I need to apply specific styling to `#myDiv` in each case.

Comment: Keep iterating `nextSibling` until you find a match or you reach the last sibling

Comment: @Oriol in my case I need to do it once, as I expect a to follow right after #myDiv, so I need to check if it actually is an anchor tag or nothing or something else.

Comment: @alirezasafian oh, my bad

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
document.getElementById('myElement').nextElementSibling.tagName == 'A'
```

Make sure you use `nextElementSibling`, not `nextSibling` in order to be able to check the tag name.

See here:

```js
console.log(check('myElement'));
console.log(check('almostRightElement'));
console.log(check('rightElement'));
console.log(check('noSiblings'));

function check(id){
  var el = document.getElementById(id).nextElementSibling;
  return !!el && el.tagName == 'A' && el.className == 'item';
  /* 
     used !!el just to make the check function always return a boolean
     it is not necessary as nextElementSibling will return null if
     no element is found, and since null is falsy, it will break the chain anyway
  */ 
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="myElement"></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<div>
  <div id="almostRightElement"></div>
  <a></a>
</div>
<div>
  <div id="rightElement"></div>
  <a class="item"></a>
</div>
<div>
  <div id="noSiblings"></div>
</div>
```